# Lion previous versions working for restore, but UI bindings not updated after performing restore

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, versions, nsdocument

I'm working on an app currently, and was scratching my head thinking that previous versions wasn't working; however it turns out that closing the document window and re-opening after a restore the restored values are now displayed.

The problem arises after performing the restore, the UI simply doesn't reflect that a restore has taken place.

Does anybody know of why this could be / how to fix the issue?

Thanks,
Clint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it had nothing to do with the restoreFromCoder etc.

It was where the document object was being stamped over each time, this doesn't update the UI as UI updates a performed when a property is set, thus resulting in the binding being invalidated.

The way I got around this, was by every time it loads from a document, it simply "assimilates" the new document objects values into the existing ones (initialised to defaults in init); this results in the UI updating seamlessly when the user restores.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the [required API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/restoreStateWithCoder%3a) for restoring the UI state of your windows? If you don't know what I'm talking about, you need to read [this section of the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26).